# ¿Cómo hacer para que al pegar el enlace de tu página a WhatsApp salga un icono?

Tags: html

Esta es mi página Web personal: [Web en HTML](http://carlosaragones.epizy.com/index.html)

Lo que quiero hacer es que al pegar el enlace en WhatsApp salga el típico icono encima. La línea de código es esta: 
Pero no funciona y no sé por qué.

Adjunto foto de en qué parte está puesto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo un tutorial de como se hace pero la diferencia es que a mi no me funciona: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAMU94Lq3Ws&list=PLjrN7wFjxLqhImHImyRv5hYA1swqaAYyd&index=12&t=71s

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código como texto y no como imagen. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Mira esto (en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100917/showing-thumbnail-for-link-in-whatsapp-ogimage-meta-tag-doesnt-work

Menciona que debes agregar el atributo `itemprop` a la meta etiqueta og:image.

Comment: Si bien un enlace puede ayudar a resolver el problema, no es buen visto responder solamente con el mismo. Además la pregunta tiene defectos y no cumple los parámetros mínimos de [ask]. Tu respuesta es mas bien un comentario. Te invito a repasar [answer]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

yo hice lo mismo pero con una cuenta de twitter:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com" ; target="_blank">
  <img src="https://1000marcas.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Logo-Twitter.png" alt="TWITTER" width="120px" height="80px" border=0/></a>
```

Comment: lo sé, solo cambias los links.